# SpringMVC get Model from previous call

Tags: spring-mvc, model, thymeleaf

My setup is pretty simple.
I have a Controller with a get- and a postmethod. The getmethod fills a Model which is then used to render a thymeleaftemplate of an HTML-form.

When the User clicks submit the formdata will be posted to the postmethod. This method then performes some businesslogic which may have two outcomes.

First possibilty: Everything works well and a redirect to the getmethod is performed.

Second Possibility: An exception occurs. In that case the user shall be presented with the same form he submitted containing the data he tried to submit. So in that case my postmethod returns the identifying String of the same template as the getmethod. But thymeleaf tells me that the model is lacking some attributes.
Why doesn't spring inject the same model in the postmethod that has been used to render the template of the getmethod.

Is there any way, to recycle the model from the getcall in the postmethod?

Comment: show us the code. You have to set the model attributes again in your post method to be available for the view rendered by the post method. This is because they are in request scope and last only for 1 request.

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla That is the answer I expected to hear. So I already did what you suggested and it works. I posted this question in the hope that there is a simpler way which would beenfit the simplicity of my code and performace (because i have to make several db-querys to initialize the model attributes). Thanks anyways.

Comment: I didn't say session because using session will have its own problems. Keeping your requests stateless as much as possible is good. DB queries shouldn't be an issue because the recently accessed query should be faster the next time it is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually redirect after a post method by using the `RedirectAttributes`. It is used to add data to the model even in a redirect.

This is an example of how to use it:

```
@PostMapping("/course")
public String addCourse(@RequestParam("course") Course course, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    // show a popup that the `account.name` has been added 
    redirectAttrs
      .addAttribute("course", course)
      .addFlashAttribute("message", "Course created!");

    return "redirect:/courseOverview";
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have my mind on some other things right now, but i will try it next week, and give you an upvote if it improves my code.